# Merge two properties using JSON-LD framing

Tags: json-ld

I'm trying to standartize a property in a json-ld document. A simple example:

*json-ld*

```
{
  "@context": {
    "rdfs": "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#",
    "dcterms": "http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
  },
  "@graph": [
    {
      "@id": "1",
      "rdfs:label": "A title"
    },
    {
      "@id": "2",
      "dcterms:title": "Another title"
    }
  ]
}
```

*frame (failing attempt)*

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "title": ["rdfs:label", "dcterms:title"]
  }
}
```

This produces an empty graph, instead of this:

*desired output*

```
[{
  "title": "A title"
},
{
  "title": "Another title"
}]
```

The documentation at https://json-ld.org/primer/latest/#framing seems to be work in progress and there is really not a lot of examples or tutorials covering json-ld framing.

[Playground example](https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-expanded&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22rdfs%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%22%2C%22dcterms%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2F%22%7D%2C%22%40graph%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%221%22%2C%22rdfs%3Alabel%22%3A%22Sometimes%20this%22%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%222%22%2C%22dcterms%3Atitle%22%3A%22Sometimes%20that%22%7D%5D%7D&frame=%7B%7D&context=%7B%7D)

Comment: Your examples lack a JSON-LD @context and therefore are not JSON-LD. Your properties sometimes_this_title / sometimes_that_title must be expandable to a full http URI

Comment: Extensive documentation about framing can be found in the [JSON-LD 1.1 Framing](https://w3c.github.io/json-ld-framing/) spec.

Comment: @aveltens, maybe I oversimplified the example in the attempt to make it easier to read. I'll update the question with valid json-ld syntax.

Comment: Would be nice to have a context in the frame and the desired output as well. But I think I understood what you are trying to do and dared to give an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Framing is used to shape the data in a JSON-LD document, using an example frame document which is used to both match the flattened data and show an example of how the resulting data should be shaped

https://json-ld.org/spec/latest/json-ld-framing/#framing

This beeing said, re-shaping data does not mean you can change the semantics. `rdfs:label` and `dcterms:title` are different things in the source data and will be different things in the result, you can not merge them to a "title" property that expands to only one URI (which one?). If that were the case, the result would have different semantics than the source, but framing is only meant to change the structure.